# Calling a function in a header file

Tags: c, gcc, java-native-interface, header-files

I want to know how to call a function in a header file.

For example..

```
example.h

#ifndef NPT_IMM32_H
#define NPT_IMM32_H

#ifndef NPT_API
    #ifdef  _THIS_IS_IMPLE_
        #define NPT_API     __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define NPT_API     __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif 
#endif 

NPT_API char * __stdcall npt_GetVer();
```

I want to call npt_GerVer() function in calling.c JNI file

```
calling.c
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "example.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_FingerPrintJNI_GetVer(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj){
    // Here How to call the npt_GerVer() function ? 
    return;
}
```

As you can see, I want to call "npt_GerVer() function" in Java_FingerPrintJNI_GetVer function. 
How can I do that?

Comment: That's not how headers are supposed to be used, neither in C nor C++. Althoughj C++ has more complex rules. They are different languages. State your actual problem and pick **one** of the languages. The read a book/tutorial for that language.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry It's my mistake. I changed calling.h to calling.c. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function gets called in exactly the same way and manner, whether it is declared in a header file, or in the actual translation unit itself.

In this case:

```
npt_GetVer();
```

That's it. It doesn't matter where the function is declared, as long as its declared before it's use or reference.

The only requirement is that the header file gets included. During the preprocessing phase, all header files are logically inserted at their `#include` reference, as if the contents of the header file logically replace the `#include` statement. The end result is a single `C++` translation unit.

If you were to manually replace all `#include` statements with the contents of the corresponding header files (mindful of conditional compilation, include guards, etc...) the end result will be exactly the same.

Your original question was tagged `C++`, but you are referring to `C`; however this applies equally well to `C` or `C++`.

Comment: Good answer, but you should add the fact that you also need to link the object file or library file that contains that function in as well or you will get an undefined reference when the program is linked together.